# How to count and output total number of loops in visual basic console application?

Tags: vb.net, loops, console, console-application, counter

I am learning visual basic and wrote a simple visual basic console application to do "half or triple plus one" calculations and the console app works but I would also like to count and display the total number of loops run to get to the solution. Here is my code:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim n As Double
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a starting number.")
    n = Console.ReadLine()

    Do While n <> 1

        Do While n > 1

            If n Mod 2 = 0 Then
                n = n / 2
            Else
                n = (n * 3) + 1

            End If
            Console.WriteLine(n)
        Loop
        If n = 1 Then
            Console.WriteLine(
            n = Console.ReadLine()
        End If

    Loop



    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub
```

I can't seem to find anything that counts and displays the number of loops.

Comment: Add a counter variable, increment it on each pass through the loop, and output it using Console.WriteLine just like you're outputting `n`.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not misunderstanding you, The problem solves Introducing a new variable named j, and the final code results in

```
Sub Main()
Dim n As Double
Dim j as integer
Console.WriteLine("Enter a starting number.")
n = Console.ReadLine()
j = 0

Do While n <> 1

    Do While n > 1
        'Every Time i enter in the cicle, the "operation counter" increses by one
        j = j + 1

        If n Mod 2 = 0 Then
            n = n / 2
        Else
            n = (n * 3) + 1

        End If
        Console.WriteLine(n)
    Loop
    If n = 1 Then
        Console.WriteLine(
        n = Console.ReadLine()
    End If

Loop

Console.WriteLine("I make " & j & " operations to get here!")
Console.ReadLine()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Sub Main()
        Dim n As Double
        Console.Write("Enter a starting number: ")
        n = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine())
        Console.WriteLine()

        Dim loopsCounter As Integer = 0

        Do While n > 0
            Do While n > 1
                loopsCounter += 1

                If n Mod 2 = 0 Then
                    n = n / 2
                Else
                    n = (n * 3) + 1
                End If

                Console.WriteLine(n)
            Loop

            Console.WriteLine()
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} loops to result.", loopsCounter))

            If n = 1 Then
                Console.WriteLine()
                Console.Write("Enter another number: ")
                n = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine())
                loopsCounter = 0
            End If
        Loop

        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
```